# Poor perfomance of LibGdx/Box2D on mobile devices

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I have problem with handling ~1000 objects. This number of objects affects on performance (max 21 fps on Samsung Galaxy A6+). Most of them (95%) are static.

I've tried to set all of these static bodies inactive and apply filter masks, but it didn't increase number of fps. Even decreasing VelocityIterations doesn't help much. I'm able to maintain constant 60 fps only when I don't create all static bodies.

```
world.step(1/60f, 6, 2); //my default setting

///////////////////////////////

//experimentally for all static objects:
body.setActive(false);
body.setSleepingAllowed(true);
body.setAwake(false);
```

I'm thinking of runtime destroying and creating new bodies which are near main character, but I doubt it is a proper way to solve the problem.

Comment: Have you ruled out the graphics being the bottle neck? You could quickly check by skipping any calls to draw.

Comment: The first step in debugging performance issues is to identify the cause. It seems like you are just guessing what's causing the issue making changes based on that assumption. Try adding some profiling with the PerformanceCounter and identify what part of the code is slowing you down and update your question.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I've already figured out that neither physics nor textures is slowing my game, but Box2DDebugRenderer which is the cause. I disabled it and now it's constant 60 fps.